# div completely covers page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that I want to completely cover a page. I don't want anything on the page to be showing. The div should overlay on the page and hide everything on it. To create such an overlay I use the following CSS:

```
.overlay {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

But if the page that the overlay is over is too long, some parts of the page still shows. How can I make it so that the div completely covers the page? Setting the position to fixed doesn't help because the overlay is multi pages long and the scrollbars get wracked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS that you're going to want to use for the overlay div is this.

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

This should completely cover the page with a black div.

Comment: I have tried this code and it works perfectly for me, no matter the size of the page

Comment: the problem is the div is multi pages long. And setting position to fixed screws up the scrolls bar

Comment: I tried the code myself and it works fine. When you say multiple pages long, do you mean that there is a vertical scroll because I tried that as well and it works fine.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with a working version if you want to see it https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoconr/rxyuooLc/